# Javascript target multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS:

```
  function init_selectAllFull(){
        $('#select-all-perms input, #user_full_access_to_all_shows').click(function() {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            $('#show-permissions-list').find('input[type=checkbox].full_access').each(function() {
            if (checked) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                $(".internal.external[value='none']").prop('checked', true);
                $(".external[value='none']").prop('checked', true);
                $(".internal[value='none']").prop('checked', true);
                $(".external.internal[value='none']").prop('checked', true);

            }
                $(this).trigger("change");
            });
        });
  }
```

It checks a bunch of radio fields when user unchecks a field. 
This works  but I don't like the following code, there's too much repetition going on.

```
$(".internal.external[value='none']").prop('checked', true);
$(".external[value='none']").prop('checked', true);
$(".internal[value='none']").prop('checked', true);
$(".external.internal[value='none']").prop('checked', true);
```

Is there a cleaner way to target multiple classes? any help would be greatly appreciated. 
thank you so much!

Comment: There is no difference between `$(".internal.external[value='none']")` and `$(".external.internal[value='none']")`[(See Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/z2f1phhL/)

Comment: nice! I'll remove duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain selectors in jquery like so:

```
$(".internal.external[value='none'], .external[value='none'], .internal[value='none'], .external.internal[value='none']").prop("checked", true);
```

Think of it like in a CSS file, where you can style multiple classes or elements by separating the selectors of a style block with commas:

```
.row1, .row2 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```